# MVC 3 partial view validation problem

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm trying to validate a form in a Partal View using the `DataAnnotations`.

The problem is when I check if the form is valid in the javascript, it always returns true, even if the form doesn't meet the requirements.

This is the line who always returns true: `var valid = $("#create-language-form").valid();`

In my **model** I got this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

In my **view** I got this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "create-language-form" }))
{
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
}
```

In my **javascript** I got this:

```
$("#create-language-dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('#create-language-dialog').load("/Languages/CreatePartial", { id: objectid });
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var valid = $("#create-language-form").valid();

                if (valid) {
                 //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

What might be wrong? Anything I miss to make the MVC validation work in a partial view?

Comment: Have you included `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your layout?

Answer (score 2):

This will validate the form and return true or false.

```
var valid = $("#create-language-form").validate().form();
```

Comment: `var valid` still return true even when the model is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I wrote my own function as below

```
function isFormValid() {
    var valid = true;

    $(".field-validation-error").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("data-valmsg-for") == "Name") {
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    return valid;
}
```

This will check for elements corresponding to `ValidationMessageFor` which are in error. My page had multiple forms and I wanted this to only work for few fields on a form so I added the if condition on `data-valmsg-for`. If you have got a single form and want to check if any field is in error then you can have it as below

```
function isFormValid() {
    var valid = true;

    $(".field-validation-error").each(function () {
        valid = false;
    });

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: While that will work, it doesn't really answer the question of why the unobtrusive validation is not working.